# andengine motion event view and camera

Tags: android, view, camera, andengine

i use this code for displays two view mRenderSurfaceView and gestureOverlayView:

```
            relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        final FrameLayout.LayoutParams relativeLayoutLayoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT , RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT );

        gestureOverlayView = new GestureOverlayView(this);
        gestureOverlayView.setEnabled(true);

        this.mRenderSurfaceView = new RenderSurfaceView(this);
        this.mRenderSurfaceView.setRenderer(mEngine);
        surfaceViewLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(super.createSurfaceViewLayoutParams());          

        gestureOverlayView.addOnGesturePerformedListener(this);

        relativeLayout.addView(this.mRenderSurfaceView, surfaceViewLayoutParams);
        relativeLayout.addView(gestureOverlayView, 1248,1152);
        gestureOverlayView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        this.setContentView(relativeLayout, relativeLayoutLayoutParams);
```

i drawn with this:

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent paramMotionEvent) {
    //TODO Auto-generated method stub   

if(paramMotionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
     isDrawing = true;

 }
//TouchEvent
 if(paramMotionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
    isDrawing = false;
    rec = new Rectangle[250];
    Arrays.fill( rec, null );
    irec=0; 
 }
 if (isDrawing = true) {

    if (rec[249]!=null){
     return false;
 }


    rec[irec] = new Rectangle(paramMotionEvent.getX(), paramMotionEvent.getY(), 1, 1);
    if (irec != 0) {
       Line l = new Line(rec[irec-1].getX(), rec[irec-1].getY(), rec[irec].getX(), rec[irec].getY());
       l.setColor(0.5f, 1f, 0.3f);
       mScene.attachChild(l);
    }
    irec++;
 }
 return true;
 }
```

and in OnloadScene i this `gestureOverlayView.setOnTouchListener(this);`

my Scene do 1248*1152, the problem is public boolean onTouch works fine if i in up left but if move down in scene or right the drawn is shift. how make a view with good Width and height (I guess that is the problem, this keep camera ratio) ?

if i use mScene.setOnSceneTouchListener the drawn is ok but the gesture don't work ...

Comment: in public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) { i same problem, I can not recover the data getY(), getX(), getRawY() or getRawX() correctly ..

Answer (score 0):

Solved by velocityOnScreenControl.attachChild(l); of (private AnalogOnScreenControl velocityOnScreenControl;) Use AnalogOnScreenControl example.

Comment: velocityOnScreenControl is not good the objet move with the camera ... if add in Scene this appear in upper left in the screen , maybe help me ?